# There's an algorithm that I don't exactly understand what it does and it is part of my homework.

Tags: graph-theory

Also there are 3 questions that I can't seem to find an answer for. Could you at least point me in the right direction if not help me solve these exercises?

for $(e ∈ E)$ do

{

$a(e) ← 1$;

}

$E+ ← \{e ∈ E : a(e) > 0\}$;

while $(G+ = (V, E+)$ contains a cycle $C)$ do

{

let $C = M1 ∪ M2$, where $M1$ and $M2$ are matchings with $a(M1) >= a(M2)$;

for $(e ∈ E(C))$ do

if $(e ∈ M1)$ then $a(e) + +;$

else $a(e) − −$;

$E+ ← \{e ∈ E : a(e) > 0\}$;

}

return $E+;$

//end of algorithm

(i)after each while iteration, for every $u ∈ V$ ,
$X$
$uv∈E+$
$a(uv) = p$;

(ii) the algorithm doesn’t end as long as there are edges $e$ with $0 < a(e) < p$; at the end of the
algorithm $a(e) = p$, $∀e ∈ E+$, and $E+$ is the set edge of a perfect matching in $G$;

(iii) the number of the while iterations is finite, at the end of the algorithm $f(E+) = np2/2 = pm$,
and the total length of all cycles is at most $pm$;

Comment: Your indents are missing. Where do the loops and conditional expressions end?

Comment: Oh sorry. There you go, fixed :D

Comment: The first for loop does nothing, $E+ = E$ and hence $G+ = G$ till before the while loop.